# Power BI internal report (not Azure) in my ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, powerbi, report

How can I show a Power BI internal report that is not online and not on Azure in my ASP.NET Core application?

I tried iframe but it has limitations and I need something like a report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

IFrame is the only option for embedding content from Power BI Report Server.  For Paginated Reports only you can generate PDF/Excel/Etc exports and send those to your users who don't access the Report Server directly.  Eg [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16)